# How to ensure that a npm dependency does not require a higher node version?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Say the parent package has a minimum required node version specified in `package.json`:

```json
"engines": {
  "node": ">=12"
},
```

Then a dependency is installed that requires a higher node version in its own `package.json`:

```json
"engines": {
  "node": ">=14"
},
```

Running `npm i`, `npm ci` does not show any error when executed in a Node 12 (or even lower) environment.

How can I detect that the minimum required node version of a dependency is higher than that of the parent package as part of CI?

Comment: What does npm report your [engine-strict](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#engine-strict) config is set to?  i.e. Utilizing the [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config) command If you run `npm config get engine-strict` what does it return? Is it `true`/`false`?  If it returns `true` and the package that requires a higher node version than you're using gets installed regardless perhaps you're encountering [issue #1219](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1219). Or are you actually wanting to detect `engines.node` conflicts prior to running `npm ci`?

Comment: The `engine-strict` is not set, but in my understanding it works differently. A dependency is compatible with the host package, even if the host package suggest it works on a lower node engine version. I did not find any solution for this, but a wrote a script instead that checks that and blocks the CI if that is the case. Maybe I'll release it as GitHub App in the future.

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. A custom script currently seems the way to go. I'd probably approach this by **1)** Utilizing the [npmgraphbuilder](https://github.com/anvaka/npmgraphbuilder) pkg to build a graph (essentially JSON) of the full transitive dependency tree - this is what [this online tool](https://npm.anvaka.com/#/) utilizes. **2)** Iterate each entry/package in the resultant JSON to obtain the `engines.node` metadata, then compare/test it against the installed node.js version using the [semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver) pkg.

Comment: Except for 1), that is exactly how I did it.